# Python Debugging

Tags: python, debugging, ide, breakpoints

I'm not sure if 'debugging' is the right word, but I'm looking for a tool/IDE that would show my which statement/block will be executed next in a particular module. This feature I remember was available in Turbo C++ years back so I assume something similar might be available in some Python IDE?

Thanks

Comment: A code sample of where you're getting confused would help.  You should spend more time writing clear readable code and less time in the debugger.  Please post the code that confuses you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python, searching is not that hard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) has this feature - [there's a nice hands-on tutorial about it here](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2009/09/10/debugging-in-python/).

[pydev](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_debugger.html), the eclipse python plugin, might help if you're looking for an IDE solution.

Comment: pdb is perfect, just what I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 1):

[Ulipad IDE](http://code.google.com/p/ulipad/)'s debugging feature is very good, its just works like Turbo C++ IDE's debugger.

Answer (score 0):

At the commandline, there's [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html)

In an IDE, Netbeans has [a GUI debugger](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Nbpythondebuggerprimer) that some people like.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Netbeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/index.html).. very good (and improving) python support.. 
you will have to install the python plugin if you download the standard installer..